# how to get the output from where number started and till end

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a column called `NARRATION` in my table and it has values as below.

```
NARATION
--------
Ram 12345678  
Kiran 12.23.4523  
Bhaskar 43/23/45767-12  
Deep sand 12.2334.3444
```

I want to get the output from narartion from where number started and till end

```
12345678  
12.23.4523  
43/23/45767-12  
12.2334.3444
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck. (As an aside, when you store your data poorly, you have to jump through hoops to use it. Properly normalizing makes it much easier.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `REGEXP_INSTR`, which finds first occurrence of numeric character in the string and then `SUBSTR`, which extract all characters till end.

```
SELECT SUBSTR (name_num, REGEXP_INSTR (name_num, '[0-9]')) FROM NARATION;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d6ab5/34)